# SNAP! 4.0 could not connect to server

Tags: mit-scratch

I downloaded SNAP! from github and everything work without problem, but it not connect to snap.apps.miosoft/SnapCloud, snap online version connect but this local version not connect. what can i do?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `snap.apps.miosoft.com/SnapCloud`

Comment: I'm not familiar with Snap, but maybe this thread answers your question: https://github.com/jmoenig/Snap--Build-Your-Own-Blocks/issues/1284

Comment: I've had the same issue. Just go to your history and go to clear and check cache and website data. That should solve the problem